# \thispagestyle affects all pages

Tags: fancyhdr, pagestyle

I have a problem withe the `\thispagestyle` command: If I use it on the first page of my article, not only the style of this page changes, but all following pages are also affected.
It seems that all other pages reserve the same space for a header which is emtpy. Thus, alle the text on these pages "slides" down, even out of the page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,twocolumn,9pt]{article}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage[super,sort&compress,comma]{natbib} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.785cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{times,mathptmx}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fnpos}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
\renewcommand{\refname}{References}}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{droidsans}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{example-image}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

%%%PAGE SETUP - Please do not change any commands within this section%%%
\makeFNbottom
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE{15pt}{17}}
\renewcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large{12pt}{14}}
\renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large{10pt}{12}}
\renewcommand\footnotesize{\@setfontsize\footnotesize{7pt}{10}}
\renewcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize{7pt}{7}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{1pt}% 
\color{cream}\hrule width 3.5in height 0.4pt \color{black} \vspace*{5pt}} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1}            
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]% 
{\noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{\@thefnmark\,}#1}
\makeatother 
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\small{Fig.}~}
\sectionfont{\sffamily\Large}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize}
\subsubsectionfont{\bf}
\setstretch{1.125} %In particular, please do not alter this line.
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.8cm}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.25cm}
\setlength{\jot}{10pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{4pt}{4pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{15pt}{1pt}
%%%END OF PAGE SETUP%%%

%%TITLE AND AUTHORS%%%
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \vspace{3cm}
    \sffamily
    \begin{tabular}{m{4.5cm} p{13.5cm} }    
    & \noindent\LARGE{\textbf{Title}} \\%Article title goes here instead of the text "This is the title"
        & \vspace{0.3cm} \\ & \noindent\large{Author} \\         & \\       
    \end{tabular}   
\end{@twocolumnfalse} \vspace{0.6cm}
]
%%%END OF TITLE AND AUTHORS%%%

%%%MAIN TEXT%%%%
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

I hope my problem became clear and someone can help.
Regards

Edit: the second page of the compiled article looks like this: [image]

As you can see, there is no footer or page number, and even parts off the text are missing.

Comment: What the problem is in unclear to me. Could you add an image showing it. BTW your code does not compile. Write `example-image` and `\lipsum[1-20]`

Comment: Probably it is not connected to the issue, but using `sectsty` together with `titlesec` is going to be problematic.

Comment: Thank you for comment! But as you already guessed, it does not solve my original problem.